# passing parameter to dowork?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am calling this zip_threading class in another class.  `string a = zip_threading(?,?)`but the problem is that how can i pass the parameter values when i am calling this class which are : String [] files, bool IsOriginal. i have used in this class background worker threading, so the real problem is that passing the value to this class and then return a value when processing is finished in make_zip_file class.

```
public class zip_threading
{

    public string[] files { get; set; } // to be recieved by the zip method as zip file names.
    public int number;
    public string return_path;
    public bool IsOriginal { get; set; }  // to be recieved by the zip method as boolean true or fales
    public static BackgroundWorker bgw1 = new BackgroundWorker(); // make a background worker object.
public void bgw1_RunWorkerCompleted(Object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        make_zip_file mzf1 = e.Result as make_zip_file;
        return_path = mzf1.return_path;

    }
    public make_zip_file bgw_DoWork(string[] files, bool IsOriginal, make_zip_file argumentest)
    {

        Thread.Sleep(100);
        argumentest.return_path = argumentest.Makezipfile(files,IsOriginal);
        return argumentest;

    }
    public void run_async(string []files,bool IsOriginal)
    {

        make_zip_file mzf2 = new make_zip_file();
       // mzf2.files = files;
        //mzf2.IsOriginal = IsOriginal;

        bgw1.DoWork += (sender, e) => e.Result = bgw_DoWork(files, IsOriginal, mzf2);
        bgw1.RunWorkerAsync();

}
 public  class make_zip_file
    {
        public string return_path ;
        //public string[] files{get;set;}
       // public bool IsOriginal{get;set;}


        public string Makezipfile(string[] files, bool IsOriginal)
        {

            string[] filenames = new string[files.Length];
            if (IsOriginal)
                for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
                    ***filenames[i] = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + files[i].Remove(0, 10).ToString();***
            else
                for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
                    ***filenames[i] = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + files[i].Replace(HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString(), "");***
            string DirectoryName = filenames[0].Remove(filenames[0].LastIndexOf('/'));
            DirectoryName = DirectoryName.Substring(DirectoryName.LastIndexOf('/') + 1).Replace("\\", "");

            try
            {

                string newFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "images\\Thumbnails\\zipFiles\\" + DirectoryName + ".zip";
                if (File.Exists(newFile))
                    File.Delete(newFile);
                using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
                {

                    foreach (string file in filenames)
                    {

                        string newfileName = file.Replace("\\'", "'");
                        zip.CompressionLevel = 0;
                        zip.AddFile(newfileName, "");
                    }

                    zip.Save(newFile);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception during processing {0}", ex);

                // No need to rethrow the exception as for our purposes its handled.
            }

            return_path = "images/Thumbnails/zipFiles/" + DirectoryName + ".zip";
return return_path;
}}
```

now i am calling this method in other class: like this

```
String path=zipa.run_async(fileCollection, IsOriginal);
```

**I get error in make_Zip_File, and i mark that with** : Object reference not set to an Instance of an object* `filenames[i] = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + files[i].Remove(0, 10).ToString();`***

Comment: Do you mean that you want to pass one parameter or multiple parameters?

Comment: i want to pass two parameters and return the result to other class, from where i am calling this class.method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use lambda functions to get a nicer syntax. When registering handler for `DoWork`, you can create lambda that calls the function and assigns the result to the `Result` property:

```
make_zip_file mzf2 = new make_zip_file(); 
bg.DoWork += (sender, e) => 
    e.Result = DoWork(files, isOriginal, mzf2);
bgw1.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Then, the `DoWork` method does just the computation and isn't tightly coupled with internals of the `BackgroundWorker` type:

```
public make_zip_file DoWork
   (string[] files, bool isOriginal, make_zip_file argumentest) {
      Thread.Sleep(100);
      argumentest.return_path = argumentest.Makezipfile(files, IsOriginal);
      return argumentest;
}
```

Comment: I like your answer but I am make_zip_file is name of a class and inside that class i have a function that return a string. name is: makezipfile(string [] files, bool IsOriginal), so how can i do this

Comment: where should i use the earlier paragraph?

Comment: @safi: The first paragraph should go into your `run_async`. If you have other problems, please clearly write what you tried and what didn't work (in what way).

Answer (score 5):

You pass the arguments through when calling bgw1.RunWorkerAsync().

EG:

```
bgw1.RunWorkerAsync(IsOriginal)
```

OR

```
bgw1.RunWorkerAsync(new object[] {IsOriginal})
```

Answer (score 3):

Pass the data while calling RunWorkerAsync

```
BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(Object)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to pass in multiple arguments to the `BackgroundWorker` then you could wrap up all the parameters in one object and pass in that one object.

Just make a new class that contain one list of files as well as your IsOriginal.

Comment: @safi: Don't worry about the BackgroundWorker. Just create a very simple normal class that has 2 members, one a list of files and one your isOriginal. Then create an instance of it just as normal. Then send that instance in as the parameter to the BackgroundWorker.

Comment: @safi: Or otherwise look at Tomas answer that I think solves the same issue but in a neater way (assuming that you're not using an old version of C#).

Comment: @ho 1: I have done what you have suggested, now the actual problem is that i want to return the value from it and pass to it as well..

Comment: @safi: You could just have a third value in the class you created and then keep a reference to the instance of that class in your calling code, then your BackgroundWorker could just set that value when it's finished. Though you would have to take care about synchronizing it since it'll be used from multiple threads (you could start by looking at the docs for the `SyncLock` statement).

Comment: @safi: Though this might make it even more worthwhile to instead go with Tomas answer (depending on your C# version). It might look a bit more complicated, but after you get over that initial hurdle it should be better for you.